# Would Appreciate some help one SQL query with Complex subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is the scenario:

I need to extract the event combinations of a particular id, and sort the order of the combinations

Here is the data:

```
EventId AppId
1   100
2   100
3   100
1   101
2   101
3   102
1   102
2   103
3   104
1   105
2   106
3   106
1   107
2   107
3   107
1   108
2   108
3   109
1   110
2   110
3   112
1   111
2   111
3   113
```

the results should look like this

```
COMBINATIONS | COUNT

1, 2, 3      |  15
1, 2         |  13
1, 3         |  10
1            |  9
2            |  7
3            |  5
```

（Not exact count from the above list)

How to compose the query to get the above result.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What database engine? My guess is that the solution will be different per each one

Comment: What is the logic, 3 = 5, but there are 7 entries for 3

Comment: you should make your desired results match the input so it is clearer what you are trying to do

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What I need is to add EventId of the same AppId into an array, and then sort the array by counts.  It can be done in PostgreSQL :  https://mkyong.com/database/convert-subquery-result-to-array/

Comment: But I need it in SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select events, count(*) as cnt
from (select appid,
             string_agg(event_id, ',') within group (order by event_id) as events
      from TestGroup t
      group by appid
     ) a
group by events;
```

Comment: This is a better answer than my own , Thanks. Gordon!

Comment: For a proper working query with real table names:           
select events, count(*) as cnt
from (select AppId, string_agg(TestId, ',') within group (order by TestId) as events
      from  TestGroup  group by AppId) as Tid group by events order by cnt desc;

Comment: This edit area sucks, it does not allow carriage return to add blank line.